# Should I use a blog app in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-apps

I want to create my own admin panel and every users will can have their own blogs. I'm using a blog app called 'Zinnia', I liked it. Zinnia have some visual editors (WYMEditor, Tinymce) also have a tag system, etc. that I want to have in my admin panel.

I was wondering if should I create my own admin panel or blog app and integrate the visual editor programatically. What would be better?

Thanks for answers.

**EDIT:** My real question is: What's better?

- create my admin and my blog app
- create my admin integrating Zinnia or another blog app
- use the django admin panel (but i want to customize the fully admin panel, so I guess that is not a good option)

Remembering, the users (not only admins) can post to their blogs. (this is the reason that I don't want to use the Django admin)

**EDIT 2:**
**Exactly what I want:** I want to use all the features (such as tagging, WYMEditor [I know i can implement this programmaticaly], etc.) of Zinnia (or another blog app) with my custom admin panel, with my buttons, my layout, my css, my everything!

Thanks for all answers, it's important for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple tutorial for creating a django blog app:

http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html

If you are still learning django, I recommend it to create your own blog!!!

Answer (score 3):

Creating a good Django blog application is straightforward, but tedious work, that can quite easily get unwieldy if you start implementing additional features such as multiple language support, linkback handling, search, sitemap generation, etc.

I definitely wouldn't suggest that you start from scratch. If your not completely satisfied by the full extent of possibilities or the initial feature set of Zinnia, you can check out all the Django blog applications on [Django Packages](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/).

Comment: I liked zinnia so much, but I want to give the users privileges to edit their blogs. But this is not my principal objective. What I want to know is: I want to use all the features of Zinnia (or another blog app) with my custom admin panel!

Comment: zinnia is not compatible with django 1.5 :(